# Como incluir Alfresco Repository no projeto

Tags: alfresco, ecm

Implementamos o Alfresco CMIS para criar, modificar e excluir arquivos conectando ao Alfresco Community (servidor), mas a gente precisaria ter o repositório incluído ao nosso projeto para não precisar ficar conectando em outro host. Não precisamos da interface (share) e muito menos da REST Api, apenas o repositório mesmo.

É possível de se fazer ou teríamos outras alternativas?